# Node readline on(close) does not get hit

Tags: node.js, readline, fs

I am playing with `createReadStream` and have a load endpoint that I want to basically read from a text file and return json data. I know the `formatted` array looks exactly like I want if I run this outside of the route, but I'm doing something stupid to break this. If I `console.log` in the `on.('close')`, I get nothing. Here is my route:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/users.txt')
});

router.route('/load')
  .get((req, res) => {
    let data = [];
    let itemised = [];
    let formatted = [];
    let tempObj = {
      "name": "",
      "phone": "",
      "email": "",
      "status": ""
    };
    readline.on('line', (line) => {
      data.push(line);
    });
    readline.on('close', () => {
      data.forEach((str) => {
        itemised.push(str.split(' '));
      })
      itemised.forEach((innerArr) => {
        const obj = innerArr.reduce(function(acc, cur, i) {
          let tempKeys = Object.keys(tempObj);
          acc[tempKeys[i]] = cur;
          return acc;
        }, {});
        formatted.push(obj);
      });
      res.json(formatted);
    });

  });
```

The .txt file looks something like this:

```
John 1234567890 jdoe@gmail.com active
Mary 0987654321 mary@gmail.com inactive
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: This is my temp workaround - Other solutions would be greatly appreciated.

While I'm still frustrated as to why I am not successful with createReadStream, I got it to work with the following solution. Which is fine, for small data files but if I wanted to tackle images or media files, I'd prefer to use readline and pipe. Anyway, for anyone who wants to see a fix that I would not put in production, here you go:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/users.txt');

router.route('/load')
  .get((req, res) => {
    let data = '';
    readStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
      data += chunk;
    }).on('end', () => {
        data = data.split("\n");
        let itemised = [];
        let formatted = [];
        let tempObj = {
          "name": "",
          "phone": "",
          "email": "",
          "status": ""
        };
        data.forEach((str) => {
          itemised.push(str.split(' '));
        })
        itemised.forEach((innerArr) => {
          const obj = innerArr.reduce((acc, cur, i) => {
            let tempKeys = Object.keys(tempObj);
            acc[tempKeys[i]] = cur;
            return acc;
          }, {});
          formatted.push(obj);
        });
        res.json(formatted);
    });
  });
```

Just FYI, I would not use this in a production level with media files due to the volume of chunks this would wait for, hence my interest in readline and pipe.